# Can the IPCapture library in Processing support loadPixels()?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to do some image analysis in Processing on an IP camera source. I can deal with images from my webcam using loadPixels(), but the IPCamera library balks (even though it extends PImage which supports loadPixels()).

Here are two versions (one is commented). The second works; the first doesn't. (Note the difference between Available and isAvailable.)

Is there something I am overlooking?

Thx.

```
//import ipcapture.*;

//IPCapture cam;

//void setup() {
//size(640, 480);
//cam = new IPCapture(this, "http://24.231.77.130:88/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=", "", "");
//cam.start();
//}

//void draw() {
//if (cam.isAvailable()) {
//  cam.read();
//}
//cam.loadPixels();
//image(cam, 0, 0);
//}

//-----------------

import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;

void setup() {
size(640, 480);
cam = new Capture(this, width, height, 30);
cam.start();
}

void draw() {

if (cam.available()) {
  cam.read();
}
cam.loadPixels();
image(cam, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart He has. He mentions it in the title, in the first sentence, and in the tags. The language is [tag:processing].

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that one version doesn't work? What does it do instead? What exactly does "balks" mean in this context? Do you see an error? Something else?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Sorry about that. In my head, `processing` was a library, and the code looked like Java or C#.  Mea culpa.

Comment: @KevinWorkman The code that begins: import processing.video.* runs fine: the webcam image is displayed and presumably the loadPixels has worked (though I'm not doing anything with the pixels yet). The code that begins: import ipcapture.* will not run. (It gives an error about nullPoint exception or Target VM failed.) If I remove loadPixels from this code it works fine: the IP camera displays properly. The IPCapture library seems to extend the PImage object, which can be operated on by loadPixels, so I can't figure out why loadPixels is crashing this sketch. Sorry if I'm being long winded here.

Comment: Please post the exact, full text of any errors or stack traces you're getting, along with exactly what line triggers them. Edit your question to include them instead of posting in comments, that way they'll be easier to read.

Comment: @user2449986 Can you not use the first part of the code without the loadPixels() call on the ```IPCapture``` instance ? (Perhaps it handles updating pixels internally as long as there's a new frame fetched) ?